# Replacing string with variable with Groovy and SED command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, groovy, sed

I am trying to replace an entire description string contained in an XML file. I would like to replace that string with a variable. I am using a SED command within a Groovy script.

I have the following code. I am expecting the string "foo" to replace the description text but it doesn't. 
Instead the following line causes the XML to change to:
**Description="sDescription"**

What am I doing wrong?

```
def sDescription = "foo"
def sedCommand = 'sed -i \'s/Description="[^"]*"/Description="'$sDescription'"/g\'  package.appxmanifest' as String
```

Comment: Why not replace it with groovy's excellent XML parsing and manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy variable/expression substitution inside of strings (interpolation) only works with certain types of string literal syntax. Single quote syntax (`'content'`) is not one of them. However, if you replace the outer single quotes with double quotes (`"content"`) then you should get the interpolation effect you are looking for:

```
def sDescription = "foo"
def sedCommand = "sed -i 's/Description=\"[^\"]*\"/Description=\"$sDescription\"/g\'  package.appxmanifest" as String
```

This should give you the string that contains the command you wish to run. Please note how I changed the special character escaping (`\`) within the string to reflect the change in string delimiters.

**Aside:** As noted by @tim_yates, Why would you want to invoke a separate *ad hoc* process to do this substitution when Groovy contains excellent XML manipulation facilities built into the language?