# jenkins escape sed command

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, escaping

Can someone escape this sed shell command in Jenkins groovy script for me?

So hard.

```
sh ("""
sed "s/(AssemblyInformationalVersion\(\")(.*)(\")/\1${productVersion}\3/g" 
AssemblyInfoGlobal/AssemblyInfoGlobal.cs -r
""")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing string with variable with Groovy and SED command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878024/replacing-string-with-variable-with-groovy-and-sed-command)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The triple-double-quote (`"""`) string literal syntax allows for variable/expression substitution (interpolation), so the backslash (`\`) is interpreted as a special character "escape". Since the first open paren is not such a special character, Groovy compilation fails. If your intent is to have literal backslashes in the resulting string, you need to escape the backslashes. That is, use a double-backslash (`\\`) to substitute for one literal backslash.

Thus:

```
sh ("""
sed "s/(AssemblyInformationalVersion\\(\\")(.*)(\\")/\\1${productVersion}\\3/g" 
AssemblyInfoGlobal/AssemblyInfoGlobal.cs -r
""")
```

Comment: It is easier to just use the snippen generator of the plugin. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator

Comment: Agreed. Or the text manipulation facilities in the Groovy language itself.

Comment: On Jenkins ver. 2.125 following worked for me: 
 script {
  sh "sed -i 's/app-host/${APPLICATION_HOST}/g' de.mms_dresden.dosv.sahi.scripts/js/scripts/antest/antest.dd.csv"
 }

Comment: @walla The Jenkins snippet generator is handy, however it always uses single quote escape, which will prevent shell variables from being expanded i.e. `'''…'''` instead of `"""…"""`.

Answer (score 7):

So if you like to replace some chars or word in an **String groovy variable**, for example **replacing** **"/"** with **"/"** in order to escape an special character, which in our case will be the forward slash you can use the code below.

So afterwards we'll be able to apply the linux sed command without getting an error (for instance using sed to replace a place holder value with the desired value in an .env file).

Below we show a **Jenkins Pipeline Groovy** code:

```
        String s = "A/B/C"
        your_variable = s.replace("/", "\\/")
        sh "sed -i -e 's/string_to_replace/${your_variable}/g' path/to/file/.env"
```

**NOTE:** `${your_variable}` will get the content of your variable.

**VALIDATION:**

```
echo "Your variable new content: ${your_variable}"
```

**RESULT:**

```
Your variable new content: A\/B\/C
```

Comment: This way makes complex shell escapes much more easy to implement, especially when needed to be done multiple times. In case you want to substitute an environment variable use `def var = env.VAR.replace('/', '\\/')`

Comment: This is silly; `sed` allows you to use any character as delimiter. `s%string_to_replace%${your_variable}%g`