# (string issues) How to do a curl POST call with a data string?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, groovyshell, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to call a curl command with the sh command, but I would get "errors parsing JSON" no matter what I try.

```
sh """
  curl -s -X POST \
    --url www.example.com
    --data \"{\'state\': \'failure\'}\"
  """
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jenkins escape sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895903/jenkins-escape-sed-command)

Answer (score 1):

The JSON standard requires double quotes around key value pairs. Looks like in your example your missing a `\` after the --url as well.

Try:

```
sh '''
    curl -s -X POST \
    -H \'Content-type: application/json\' \
    --url www.example.com \
    --data \'{"state": "failure"}\'
'''
```

If you end up needing to use String interpolation then

```
sh """
    curl -s -X POST \
    -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
    --url www.example.com \
    --data '{\"state\": \"status\"}'
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**
I think you added terminators incorrectly.

**Solution:**
Simply use this format. It should work fine.

```
curl -s -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"state":"failure"}' \
  http://www.example.com
```